# How to assign or update value in beforeUpdate hook with sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to update a database instance using beforeUpdate hook (beforeBulkUpdate actually) and the hook is triggered, but it won't update the values

**Here's my update instance**

```
let order = await Order.update(
          {
            total_days: literal(`total_days + ${days}`),
          },
          {
            where: { UserId, order_name },
          }
        );
```

**Here's my hook**

```
beforeBulkUpdate(order, option) {
          if (order.total_days > 2) {
            order.discount = order.total_due * 0.15;
          } else {
            order.discount = 0;
          }
          order.tax = 0.1 * order.total_due;
          order.total_due = order.total_due - order.discount + order.tax;
        }
```

Am I doing it wrong or is it not possible to update a value on beforeUpdate hooks?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are setting values in the function is wrong. You need to use the sequelize model.setDataValue('field-name', value) function.

```
beforeBulkUpdate(order, option) {
    if (order.total_days > 2) {
        order.setDataValue('discount', (order.total_due * 0.15));
    } else {
        order.setDataValue('discount', 0);
    }
    order.setDataValue('tax', (0.1 * order.total_due));
    order.setDataValue('total_due', (order.total_due - order.discount + order.tax));
}
```

Comment: I tried that and now it says "setDatavalue is not a function"

Comment: Huh, weird. It works fine in hooks when I encrypt stuff pre-creation and update https://pastebin.com/9UUUeh0r

Comment: before update doesn't receive instance param, just options :( please let me know if anyone has solution for beforeBulkUpdate